# Do we have a workaround for the T-SQL CONCAT_WS function?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Do we have a workaround for the T-SQL `CONCAT_WS` function? This one throws an error that

> is not a recongized built in function name

I presume this is not compatible with my version.

I am currently trying to get a proper format for my full name where MiddleName is or isn't `NULL`.

Comment: A quick peek at the [**official** Microsoft SQL Server documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) easily shows that `CONCAT_WS` is available as of SQL Server **2017** and newer....

Comment: Please excuse, I am a novice in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, SQL Server now supports [`CONCAT_WS()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).  So, using the built-in function is the simplest "work-around".

As an alternative:

```
select stuff( (coalesce(', ' + col1, '') +
               coalesce(', ' + col2, '') +
               coalesce(', ' + col3, '')
              ), 1, 2, '') as concat_ws
```

The separator and "2" need to be consistent, of course.

Comment: Wow, this one handles the NULL values just perfect. Thanks Gordon. May I know which versions support the CONCAT_WS?

Comment: SQL Server 2017+.